# What is the logic is MembershipUser.ResetPassword() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Normally, `ResetPassword(string passwordAnswer)` returns a new password for the membership user. `ChangePassword(string oldPassword,string newPassword)` takes two parameters: old and new password. I'm OK with that but in the code below:

```
string pwd = mu.ResetPassword(k.SecretAnswer);
mu.ChangePassword(pwd, k.password);
return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

According to this code, `pwd` is contains old password, but `ResetPassword()` method returns a new random password. So how can `pwd` represent old password? Shouldn't the `ResetPassword()` method return a new password? What am I missing? What is the logic is behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset password created a password that must be reset upon first usage. It is used more as a token (in the auth realm) than an actual password.

So when you called `mu.ChangePassword(pwd, k.password);`, you "exchanged" the `pwd` token for a "normal" password.

If you had skipped changing the password in the line above and tried to log in using `pwd` from the `Reset` method it would not have succeeded.
The UI would *force* you to change your password and *then login with the **new** password*.

This is designed so a user is the only one to have ever seen their password in plain text (ie unencrypted).

**EDIT:** What *exactly* is a token and what is the difference between a token and a password?

Short answer(s):

1. A **password** can be used **multiple** times while a *token* can only be used *once*.
2. A **password** is **verified** while a *token* is *redeemed*.
3. A **password** requires verification for **each use**. A *token* requires verification *before it is given*.

While both tokens and passwords are used to gain access, it's how they are used that differentiates them.

Let's try some real-world examples (granted these examples don't align 100% with our use case, but I believe they could help).

The PIN for your ATM card is a *password* because:

1. it is secret
2. it is verified each time you use it
3. you can use it over and over

If you take a suit to the dry cleaners, they hand you a ticket (with a number) that you will use to get your suit back. That's a *token* because:

1. You must physically possess the ticket to get your suit back
2. If you have the ticket, you get the suit. No questions asked. You proved it was your suit when you dropped it off.
3. Once you use it, the ticket is worthless.

Comment: When I checked the code with debug mode, pwd value contains md5 hash code. So ResetPassword() method returns new password or old password?

Comment: ResetPassword() returns a new password, but the password is flagged to require you to change your password. If you have access to the db, you can see the differences between the passwords.

Comment: So can we say pwd token contains new md5 hash and old password and this old password change with new password after changepassword method.the point i am confused is pwd has two behavior :in first line assigned with new password, second line it represents old password. I think because of i don't know what exactly token is. Sorry for keep asking but i am really trying to understand clearly.

Comment: @Hgrbz - No worries, there are a lot of nuances when it comes to security. I updated my answer, hope this clears it up.